# How do I locate Google Settings, or better Android Device Manager Settings on Android 5.0.2 MIUI 7.0?

Tags: android-device-manager, google-settings

I have trouble locating Google Settings.
Official help documentation advice doesn't apply. Maybe since I have MIUI 7.0? I'm looking for Android Device Manager Settings.

[Google Support Info](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3118621?hl=en)

Comment: Open of Google Search app, then type in `Google Settings`. Does the app show up?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer isn't related to the question actually. Please read the post by @sinchan for correct information and then mine for extended info.

Android Device Manager which comes builtin has no specific settings AFAIK. You just need to login using Google Account and manage all the devices under that account like Locating, Erasing, Locking, Ringing the devices remotely. For Android device manager to work properly keep the GPS and Mobile Data/WiFi turned on.

Additionally visit [Google My Account](http://myaccount.google.com) > Device Activity for other options.

Comment: Android Device Manager does have a specific settings place. It's usually under Google Settings in the app. The user is asking for the location of the settings in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I interpret your question in the two following ways:-

- You want to change/edit/disable your specific phone's Android Device Manager settings. In this case, you should browse to **Settings** and under the Tab for **Security**, look for something like **Device Administrators.** Over there you'll see a checked/unchecked option named **Android Device Manager**.
- Another possibility is that you want to edit the Settings of all devices associated with your Google account. In that case, simply download the **Android Device Manager** app from Google's **Play Store**. Here's the link to make it easier: [Android Device Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en)

Hope this helps!